# TFS build server running Unit tests with different configuration

Tags: mstest

I am using TFS 2013 as a build server. And I have a test project that is using the unit test framework of visual studio 2013.

I am writing unit tests that is checking rest services.

I want to run these tests for the three environments: dev/test/prod
so, I am going to have three build definitions , one for each environment.
But my question is on how to configure the config files.
Is it possible to have three config file (app.config), which will be picked by the build project?

what is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the build definition you can specify which solution configuration to be build (dev/test/prod) and you can use [SlowCheetah - XML Transforms](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) to create your different config files in the project.